# Recover data from 1 disk after broken raid 5

Tags: raid5, raid0

in a bit of an emergency. I am taking control of some servers that someone else had setup. One of them has crashed and it was critical. Here is what I found:

The server (Dell r710) was operating with one hard disk, when checking the RAID configuration, to my surprise it was setup on RAID 5, which as far as I know, it can't be. What can I do to attempt to recover the files?

I've had an idea of reconfiguring the RAID controller to RAID 0 and not initializing the disk. Would that be good?

Comment: Was the drive connected to the Raid controller or just connected to an onboard sata port?

Comment: Hey Drifter, it was connected to the Raid controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What can I do to attempt to recover the files?

Stop what you are doing. Power off the server. Remove the hard drives and ship them off to a professional data recovery shop. Period, full stop.

You haven't a clue how exactly it was configured before, and anything more you do to it will cause further issues.

> I've had an idea of reconfiguring the RAID controller to RAID 0 and
>   not initializing the disk. Would that be good?

No. Heck no. Don't even consider it.

Comment: Not just "the drive" but _all the drives_ in the array.

Comment: I would recommend cloning the contents before sending the disk(s) anywhere.

Comment: Yep, clone the disks using `dd` or equivalent.

Comment: Ok! I will consider that as an option. As a note, the odd thing here is that it was operating with a single drive on RAID 5. I've got but one drive to ship off to a data recovery company.